# C++ columnwise output

Tags: c++

New to C++ having an assignment in my study.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()

    {
        for (int i = 1, j = 1; i <= 9; i++, j++) {

            cout << setw(5) << right << i;
            if(j==3) {
                j=0;
                cout << "\n";
             }
         }
        return 0;
    }
```

yields this output:

```
1    2    3
4    5    6
7    8    9
```

However, I need this output:

```
1    4    7
2    5    8
3    6    9
```

Not permitted to use arrays. I thought this was simple (have tried an extra *for* loop, etc.), but cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Does this need to be a general solution? So if you need to print the numbers `1` to `10` or `11`, what would those look like?

Comment: Hint:  Use some math.  What is the relationship between the first and 2nd columns?  What is the relationship between the 2nd and 3rd columns?  Is division helpful?  What about remainders?

Comment: Search keyword: stride

Comment: Try something first. If it doesn't work, then ask a question. We're not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: @Obicere Yes it does. It could be any matrix with _n_ rows by _m_ columns, but counting column wise rather than row wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        std::cout << i << "\t" << (i + 3) << "\t" << (i + 6) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I would suggest that you should think on the basic maths logic to solve these kind of problems.

The above code will generate the following output:

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

Here if you see each line, you can see that each value is incremented by 3.

- When `i = 1`, the first value is i itself.
- The second value is `i+3`.
- The third value is `i+6`.